# scala groupBy class then map the results

Tags: scala, types

I have a list of elements, and want to group them by class and then process the results.

```
trait H 
case class A(x: Int) extends H
case class B(x: Int) extends H
val x = List(A(1),B(2),B(3))
val y = x.groupBy(_.getClass)

y.map(_ match {case (A, alist) => println("found me some As")
               case (B, blist) => println("not As")})
```

Unfortunately this produces errors like:

```
<console>:17: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : A.type
 required: Class[_ <: Product]
Note: if you intended to match against the class, try `case _: A`
       y.map(_ match {case (A, alist) => println("found me some As")
```

That is, I can't seem to find the proper way to do case matching when the item being matched *is* a class **not just** an instance of one.

A partial solution is the following:

```
val z = y.map(_ match {case (atype, alist) => alist })
z.map(_ match {
  case alist if alist.head.isInstanceOf[A] => alist 
  case blist => List()
})
```

But it feels like there should be a better way of doing this using the keys to the initial `Map` returned from `groupBy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` in `case (A, alist)` refers to the companion object of `A`, which has the type `A.type`. That's why you're getting that error message. If you want to match against the class meta data, you should refer to `classOf[A]`. There's also no reason to use `match`, as you can pattern match with `map` already.

```
y.map {
    case (c, alist) if(c == classOf[A]) => println("found me some As")
    case (c, blist) if(c == classOf[B]) => println("not As")
}
```