# Scala: Casting results of groupBy(_.getClass)

Tags: scala

In this hypothetical, I have a list of operations to be executed.  Some of the operations in that list will be more efficient if they can be batched together (eg, lookup up different rows from the same table in a database).

```
trait Result
trait BatchableOp[T <: BatchableOp[T]] {
  def resolve(batch: Vector[T]): Vector[Result]
}
```

Here we use [F-bounded Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699425/scala-how-to-refer-to-the-type-of-an-extending-class-in-a-superclass) to allow the implementation of the operation to refer to its own type, which is highly convenient.

However, this poses a problem when it comes time to execute:

```
def execute(operations: Vector[BatchableOp[_]]): Vector[Result] = {
  def helper[T <: BatchableOp[T]](clazz: Class[T], batch: Vector[T]): Vector[Result] =
    batch.head.resolve(batch)

  operations
    .groupBy(_.getClass)
    .toVector
    .flatMap { case (clazz, batch) => helper(clazz, batch)}
}
```

This results in a compiler error stating `inferred type arguments [BatchableOp[_]] do not conform to method helper's type parameter bounds [T <: BatchableOp[T]]`.

How can the Scala compiler be convinced that the `group` is all of the same type (which is a subclass of `BatchableOp`)?

- One workaround is to [specify the type explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278937/understanding-inferred-type-arguments-do-not-conform-to-type-parameter-bounds), but in this case the type is unknown.
- Another workaround relies on [enumerating the child types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42568924/scala-groupby-class-then-map-the-results), but I'd like to not have to update the `execute` method after implementing a new `BatchableOp` type.

Comment: sorry, i have to give up. f-bound + broken existential type in scala is to hard to tame.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Why "broken"? Did you at least manage to crash the compiler, or do you just not like existentials? ;) The existentials are "broken" mostly [for the higher kinds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48434839/2707792), but I couldn't make it crash working on this question :]

Comment: @AndreyTyukin well not broken in that sense. in the first place, existential type over co-/contra-variant types is redundant. in invariant case, existential type over type parameter is extremely useless, due to lack of way to recover information type safely; however, writing private type variable makes indeed better sense. also it's syntactically broken as shown in your answer. I personally don't like existential types due to my bad experience with it during early days and I realized whenever I wanted to use it, I did not really need it.

Comment: They are useful in those rare cases when you are writing a completely generic framework, and at some point the typed higher-level constructs have to be dismantled into a bunch of small pieces with different types, and squashed into a queue of a lower-level scheduler of some sort. Since the OP is batching jobs here, the occurrence of existentials seems appropriate, or even inevitable. But yes, you don't need them too often in the not-so-low-level parts of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to approach the question systematically, so that the same solution strategy can be applied in similar cases.

**First, an obvious remark:** you want to work with a vector. The content of the vector can be of different types. The length of the vector is not limited. The number of types of entries of the vector is not limited. Therefore, the compiler cannot prove everything at compile time: you will have to use something like `asInstanceOf` at some point.

---

**Now to the solution of the actual question:**

This here compiles under 2.12.4:

```
import scala.language.existentials

trait Result

type BOX = BatchableOp[X] forSome { type X <: BatchableOp[X] }

trait BatchableOp[C <: BatchableOp[C]] {
  def resolve(batch: Vector[C]): Vector[Result]

  // not abstract, needed only once!
  def collectSameClassInstances(batch: Vector[BOX]): Vector[C] = {
    for (b <- batch if this.getClass.isAssignableFrom(b.getClass))
    yield b.asInstanceOf[C]
  }

  // not abstract either, no additional hassle for subclasses!
  def collectAndResolve(batch: Vector[BOX]): Vector[Result] = 
    resolve(collectSameClassInstances(batch))
}

def execute(operations: Vector[BOX]): Vector[Result] = {

  operations
    .groupBy(_.getClass)
    .toVector
    .flatMap{ case (_, batch) =>
      batch.head.collectAndResolve(batch)
    }
}
```

The main problem that I see here is that in Scala (unlike in some experimental dependently typed languages) there is no simple way to write down complex computations "under the assumption of existence of a type".
Therefore, it seems difficult / impossible to transform

```
Vector[BatchOp[T] forSome T]
```

into a

```
Vector[BatchOp[T]] forSome T
```

Here, the first type says: "it's a vector of batchOps, their types are unknown, and can be all different", whereas the second type says: "it's a vector of batchOps of unknown type `T`, but at least we know that they are all the same".

What you want is something like the following hypothetical language construct:

```
val vec1: Vector[BatchOp[T] forSome T] = ???
val vec2: Vector[BatchOp[T]] forSome T = 
  assumingExistsSomeType[C <: BatchOp[C]] yield {
    /* `C` now available inside this scope `S` */
    vec1.map(_.asInstanceOf[C])
  }
```

Unfortunately, we don't have anything like it for existential types, we can't introduce a helper type `C` in some scope `S` such that when `C` is eliminated, we are left with an existential (at least I don't see a general way to do it).

Therefore, the only *interesting* question that is to be answered here is:

> Given a `Vector[BatchOp[X] forSome X]` for which I know that there is *one common type `C`* such that they all are actually `Vector[C]`, where is the scope in which this `C` is present as a usable type variable?

It turns out that `BatchableOp[C]` itself has a type variable `C` in scope. Therefore, I can add a method `collectSameClassInstances` to `BachableOp[C]`, and this method will actually have some type `C` available that it can use in the return type. Then I can immediately pass the result of `collectSameClassInstances` to the `resolve` method, and then I get a completely benign `Vector[Result]` type as output.

**Final remark**: If you decide to write any code with F-bounded polymorphisms *and* existentials, at least make sure that you have documented very clearly what *exactly* you are doing there, and how you will ensure that this combination does not escape in any other parts of the codebase. It doesn't feel like a good idea to expose such interfaces to the users. Keep it localized, make sure these abstractions do not leak anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Andrey's answer has a key insight that the only scope with the appropriate type variable is on the `BatchableOp` itself.  Here's a reduced version that doesn't rely on importing `existentials`:

```
trait Result
trait BatchableOp[T <: BatchableOp[T]] {
  def resolve(batch: Vector[T]): Vector[Result]
  def unsafeResolve(batch: Vector[BatchableOp[_]]): Vector[Result] = {
    resolve(batch.asInstanceOf[Vector[T]])
  }
}

def execute(operations: Vector[BatchableOp[_]]): Vector[Result] = {
  operations
    .groupBy(_.getClass)
    .toVector
    .flatMap{ case (_, batch) =>
      batch.head.unsafeResolve(batch)
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be reduced a little too much? `Vector[]` doesn't compile. I guess you meant something like `Vector[BatchableOp[_]]`? Indeed, it's a bit shorter then, and does not need existentials.

Comment: Good catch.  There's another option where `unsafeResolve` uses the `collect` method to match against type `T`, but you'd need a `ClassTag` instance to get around type erasure.